# INVALID COLUMN? SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, having

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   'button_flag' = CASE
                      WHEN (can_assign_supervisor = 1 AND (SUM(ISNULL(auto_assign_cap, 0) - ISNULL(assigned_today_cap, 0)) > 0)) 
                      THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                   END
FROM processor
WHERE prsn_pk = 36381
```

When I try and run the query I get the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'processor.can_assign_supervisor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am not clear why this error is happening.

- `can_assign_supervisor` is a BIT
- `auto_assign_cap` and `assigned_today_cap` are int
- `prsn_pk` is the primary key

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: you're using SUM() as an aggregate function so you should add a GROUP BY clause with the non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you want to do,

this will work

```
SELECT 
  'button_flag' = SUM(CASE
       WHEN (can_assign_supervisor = 1 AND
             (SUM(ISNULL(auto_assign_cap, 0) - ISNULL(assigned_today_cap, 0)) > 0)
            ) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END)
 FROM processor
 GROUP BY prsn_pk, can_assign_superviosor
 WHERE prsn_pk = 36381
```

as will this:

```
SELECT 
  'button_flag' = SUM(CASE
       WHEN (can_assign_supervisor = 1 AND
             (ISNULL(auto_assign_cap, 0) - ISNULL(assigned_today_cap, 0)) > 0)
            ) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END)
 FROM processor
 WHERE prsn_pk = 36381
```

Comment: yes thank you.  i also just moved can_assign_supervisor into the where clause, out of the case statement.  slow brain day.  thank you